# ASP.net core AntiForgeryToken issue : data doesn't bind to model

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-core, antiforgerytoken

I have a working project for a booking system in asp.net core that uses a google Timeline chart. When you click on the chart a modal popup with a partial view pops up up to enter data. Javacript has a click event on the save button to send the data to the controller. The controller validates the data and sends the partial view  back to javascript where it is sent back to the modal popup. I have two flags on the view that if set true, javascript hides the popup. This all works until I decorate the controller with `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]`

I have the code as follows

---

StartUp:

```
services.AddAntiforgery(options => {
    options.HeaderName = "RequestVerificationToken";
});
```

---

Javascript:

```
(function() {
        var PlaceHolderElement = $('#PlaceHolderHere');
        //create popup save
        PlaceHolderElement.on('click', '[data-save="modal"]', function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            var form = $(this).parents('.modal').find('form');
            var token = $("input[name='__RequestVerificationToken']").val();
            var actionUrl = form.attr('action');
            var sendData = form.serialize();
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: actionUrl,
                data: sendData,
            }).done(function(data1) {
                var newBody = $('.modal-body', data1);
                PlaceHolderElement.find('.modal-body').replaceWith(newBody);
                var isValid = newBody.find('[name="IsValid"]').val() === 'True';
                var isValid2 = newBody.find('[name="BookingFree"]').val() === 'True';
                if (isValid && isValid2) {
                    PlaceHolderElement.find('.modal').modal('hide');
                    location.reload();
                }
            })
})
```

---

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult EditBooking(BookingViewModel model) {

  if (ModelState.IsValid) {
    ... other code
  }
}
```

when I decorate the controller with [ValidateAntiForgeryToken] and change the jarvascript to

```
data: {
    model: sendData,
    __RequestVerificationToken: token,
}
```

the Validate works but the model is empty! if I declare the model as string then I get a string.

If I send the token in headers:, the token validation fails

I need the data in the model in order for the ModelState to set IsValid

Comment: Hi, `.serialize()` will pass the form data together with __RequestVerificationToken value by default. And the `AddAntiforgery` in Startup.cs is useless.  Could you pls share your html code?

Comment: Thank you, I have removed AddAntiforgery from StartUp.cs and added @Html.AntiForgeryToken() to my view page and it now works. Did try this before but failed. Thank you again

Comment: I have shared an answer below. Pls check.

Answer (score 1):

1.`.serialize()` will pass the form data together with `__RequestVerificationToken` value by default.

2.When you use form element with `method="post"` and tag helper, it will dynamically generate token input which `name="__RequestVerificationToken"` inside the form. But if you specific the `action` attribute for form like:`<form action="/url" method="post"></form>`, it will not generate the token input.

So if you specific the `action` attribute, you need manually add token input by using `@Html.AntiForgeryToken()` in the form:

```
<form action="/url" method="post">
     @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
     //....
</form>
```

A simple working demo you could follow:

View:

```
<form asp-action="EditBooking" asp-controller="Home" method="post">
    <input asp-for="Name" />
    <input type="button" onclick="PostForm()" value="Post" />
</form>

@section Scripts
{
    <script>    
        function PostForm() {
            //var token = $("input[name='__RequestVerificationToken']").val();
            var actionUrl = $('form').attr('action');
            var sendData = $('form').serialize();
            console.log(sendData)
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: actionUrl,
                data: sendData,
            }).done(function(data1) {                                
            })
}
    </script>
}
```

And no need add the following code:

```
services.AddAntiforgery(options => {
    options.HeaderName = "RequestVerificationToken";
});
```